# Cross-machine DLL creation using VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, win32com

I've created a DLL file using VC++ 2008 with following settings:

- Configuration type: Dynamic Library (.dll)
- Use of MFC: Use Standard Windows Libraries
- Use of ATL: Not using ATL
- Common Language Runtime support: Common Language Runtime support (/clr)

The created DLL is working perfectly on my machine (the machine it's created on) but it can't be used on another machine (I tested with 3 machines). For more details, I load this DLL file via JNI (Java Native Interface). On my machine it works, but on others it showing the error of "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:: The application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect...."

My question is:
1. Did I miss any configuration when creating the DLL that can't be worked on multiple environment?
2. Can we created a DLL file that will work on different machines?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the VC++ 2008 Redistributables have been installed on the other machines. To double check this is the problem run Dependency Walker on the other machine and it'll show you what it's looking for:
http://www.dependencywalker.com/

You can find the VC 2008 redist EXE on the microsoft web site:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

or the actual DLLs are in the redist folder in the VC 2008 install folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can google for "side-by-side configuration is incorrect" and you will find a lot of hints what the reason could be. 
But ... giv this a try first: 
In VS, project settings, C/C++, Code Generation: Set "Runtime Library" to "Multi-threaded" (or "Multi-threaded Debug". 
(Btw: Do you need Common Language Runtime support?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My "Runtime Library" configuration is already a Multi-threaded Debug. I don't really understand what's the different when using or not using CLR (forgive me because I've just started learning VC++ for 2 days). But when I use the option Not use CLR so the project can't be compiled. I guess that I've used some namespaces that requrie CLR.

Comment: /MT is not an option for /clr compiled code.  You'll need to show him how to install the CRT dlls properly.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what @snowdude says, which is correct, there is another possible problem: if these other PCs don't have VS2008 installed, and you linked to the debug MSVCR* libraries, you're out of luck. Only Release mode binaries can be deployed to user systems without hoop-jumping.